# what happens if we bind the same div twice one in js file and one as inline script

Tags: jquery

this is inside javascript file

what happenes if i have the same bindings for the same div defined twice //

```
$(document).ready(function() {     

    $("#divid").click(function() {
     // some logic here

 });
    });
```

this is as inline

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("#divid").click(function() {
// some logic here
});
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result will be that both handlers will run, in the order they were bound (unless the first interrupts the event, e.g. `return false`).

The order they're bound is the order the `<script>` elements occur in, since `.ready()` handlers are also queued in order.

Comment: I don't believe the second one will be interrupted by returning false from the first one. You'll need `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` for that.

Comment: @box9 - I was speaking more generally, as a first handler - possibly a child returning false...on the same level yes it'd have to be explicitly stopped via that method.

Comment: craver , thank you , as a quick fix we pushed something online as we don't want to push javascript files right now, thanks