# Can you define jquery's $(function(){...}) twice on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web page that pulls an external javascript file that has all of my functions in it. I'll call that file "functions.js".

functions.js has a jQuery has a `$(function(){...});` to do my operations when the page is ready. My question is, is it possible to also write another `$(function(){...}` on the body of the same page that calls functions.js, so that whatever I do in both of the domReady functions happens on the page? For example, if functions.js is:

```
$(function(){
$('div').css('color','green');
}
```

and I put this code in  tags on the page which calls functions.js:

```
$(function(){
$('div').css('background-color','red');
}
```

will the page end up making my divs have both green text AND red backgrounds, or will one override the other, or will neither work?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: i asked the same question here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394346/what-happens-if-we-bind-the-same-div-twice-one-in-js-file-and-one-as-inline-scrip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many $(document).ready() calls as you want: [http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

You could just try it you know (it would have taken less time than it did for you to type all of that out)  :)

Yes, both will run and work.

Comment: thanks! Trying it worked, but I wanted to make sure that it wasn't just a browser specific 'fluke' that it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can write as many ready functions as you like. You Do do not really need ready functions if you place your code before closing `</body>` tag and before jquery.js script.

Here's a well written blog on how document functions can slow you down and why they shouldn't be used.  http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Answer (score 2):

You can place as many as you like.

You can even place multiple `$(window).load(function() { ... })` in jQuery (thanks [cwolves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578895/cwolves)).

In JavaScript (without jQuery), a workaround must be used...

```
(function() {
   var events = [];

   var registerWindowLoadEvent = function(callback) {
       events.push(callback);
   };

   window.onload = function() {
       for (var i = 0, eventsLength = events.length; i < eventsLength; i++) {
          events[i].call();
       };
    };
})();
```

Comment: Um, what?  No...  You can place as many `$(window).load()` functions as you want.  Tested back to jQuery 1.2.6 in case this used to happend and I'd never noticed: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/TDF5e/

Comment: @cwolves Damn, I'd assumed it be [like normal JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/u4gtN/) in that regard. I've updated my post.

Comment: *smacks head*  I'd thought more of you, alex!  It's attached using `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`, just like `$('div').click`, etc.

Comment: @cwolves Ah, I avoid using them mainly when writing JavaScript code, just because of <IE9's `attachEvent()`.

Comment: @alex - what about `attachEvent` in IE9?

Comment: @cwolves I meant IE9 supporting `addEventListener()`, finally.